# how to filter API by URL on Python

Tags: regex, mongodb, api, url, eve

My DB has 2 properties("firstname" and "lastname"), I want to print all rows which have "lastname" containing "son" and "7". 
Could anyone help me to write an url to do it. I use the code below but it's print all "lastname" containing "7" only.

```
api_test = 'http://localhost:5000' + '/people?where={"lastname": {"$regex": "son", "$regex": "7"}}&page=' + str(page_num)
get_api_test = requests.get(api_test)
data = json.loads(get_api_test.text)
result = data.get('_items')
for row in result:
    print(row)
```

Comment: My DB like that

Comment: Regex should be `^(?=.*son)(?=.*7).+` or it can be `(son.*7|7.*son)` one or the other.

Comment: Please, edit your English. Use **Grammarly**, for example.

Comment: thank sir, my english is not good, i'll try to write my questions clearly in english next time.

Answer (score 0):

For the string containing `7` and `son` use the regex:

(^.*7.*son.*$)|(^.*son.*7.*$)

(https://regex101.com/r/QFpZuK/3)

It is a simple regex, without lookaheads, works everywhere.